# Meteor: load code and templates from a Collection

Tags: meteor

I'm wondering how hard it would be to hack together the following:

All of the js files, html files, css, etc -- i.e. the codebase of my meteor app -- are stored in a `Collection`, say called `Codebase`.

Thus instead of using an ordinary text editor to edit files on my filesystem, I edit documents in the Collection . Otherwise everything works like it normally does. For example, when I update a document in the `Codebase` collection, the server restarts (live reloads).

Questions:

1. Is there an easy way to do that?
2. If not, what architectural things get in the way?
3. If not, can I easily do SOME of the above scenario, for example load
   just my templates from a `Collection`?

Comment: Is it rude of me to ask why you wish to do this ? I have seen people do things like this in order to artificially circumvent release procedures, but it always creates more work than it saves in the long run. Why not use the Core Meteor hot-code reload functionality ?

Comment: @MultiMat hacking bizarre things that don't exist yet is fun and productive :)